# How can I specify image position using lower-left point coordinate in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following LaTeX code to get a TikZ picture that includes a PDF and then draws two nodes:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (label) at (0,0)[draw=black]{
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{my.pdf}
      };
      \node [draw=red] (A) at (0,0) {1};
      \node [draw=red] (B) at (2,0) {2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Simplest picture.}
\end{figure}
```

The result looks like this:

```
+---------------+
|               |
|      1 2      |
|               |
+---------------+
    Figure 1
```

So, the included PDF is centered, and coordinate `(0,0)`, where "1" is drawn, is now in the center of the picture, instead of on the bottom left of the TikZ picture as usual. How can I change it so that `(0,0)` is still at the bottom left?

It should look like this:

```
+---------------+
|               |
|               |
|1 2            |
+---------------+
    Figure 1
```

I don't want to have to use negative x coordinates to place my points on the picture.

UPDATE: Here is a screenshot of what it actually looks like. As you can see, the two red boxes are centered and not at the lower-left. (The chain with the arrows is the PDF.)
[image]

If I replace the `\includegraphics` just with an "X" I get the following picture, where the "X" and the "1" are drawn on top of each other (since they are both at coordinate `(0,0)`).

[image]

Comment: I don't see the behavior your describe. In fact, 1 and 2 show up in the lower-left as expected. Maybe it has to do with the size of the PDF? What if you just put the text 'X' in your "label" node?

Comment: I added a screenshot that shows the result I'm getting with my PDF.

Comment: What happens when you replace `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{my.pdf}` with `X` (i.e., get the PDF out of the picture).

Comment: Then everything is as expected, see the 2nd screenshot I just added.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I had to add `anchor=south west` to the node that includes the picture:

```
\node [draw=black, anchor=south west] (label) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{my.pdf}};
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: `above right` should be equivalent.